# Is there a bound on the number of connected components of a zero set of an integrable function?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, connectedness

If $f$ is a real-analytic function on a neighborhood of [0,1], and $f$ has finite differential transcendence degree (i.e. there is some $n$ such that $f^{(n)}$ can be written as a polynomial in $f, f',...,f^{(n-1)}$), is there some way to bound the number of connected components of its zero set $\{x\in [0,1]: f(x) = 0\}$, or perhaps the set where $f$ is positive, in terms of the $n$ mentioned above, the degree of the polynomial , and the size of the coefficients in the polynomial? I am thinking of the example $f(x)=\cos(\alpha x)$ for some real $\alpha$, where one always has $f'' = -\alpha^2 f$ but, as $\alpha$ becomes large, the number of connected components goes to infinity.

There is a result like this for Pfaffian functions, where the number of connected components can be bounded by the Pfaffian order and degree of $f$, but I do not know of any result that works in this more general setting.